# SQL SELECT with a default value

Tags: sql

Assuming I have an SQL table with this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE(
foo INTEGER,
bar INTEGER,
baz INTEGER DEFAULT 0
);
```

which contains data

```
foo|bar|baz
-----------
1  |1  |2
2  |3  |4
```

and I am interested in values 1,2 for `foo` and 1,2,3 for `bar`. Is there an SQL request which would return "missing" values along with the existing ones:

```
foo|bar|baz
-----------
1  |1  |2
1  |2  |0
1  |3  |0
2  |1  |0
2  |2  |0
2  |3  |4
```

? I suspect there isn't, but perhaps I just don't know it?

UPDATE:
1) using SQLite 3;
2) the missing values are given by the `DEFAULT` clause;
3) the second table shows the expected result.

Comment: what is the logic to determine the "missing" values?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'missing values'?

Comment: Is the second table an example of the output you want or just an example table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you named your table `Data`, following would get you the results you've posted.

- the `WITH` statement creates a temporary in memory table containing all Bar's from 1 to the Maximum present in your actual table.
- the `CROSS APPLY` returns a row for every bar, existing in your table or not.
- the `CASE` statement selects an existing baz if present, 0 if not.

**SQL Statement**

```
WITH q AS (
  SELECT  [bar] = 1
          , [MaxBar] = MAX(bar)
  FROM    Data
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT  q.bar + 1
          , q.MaxBar
  FROM    q
  WHERE   q.bar + 1 <= q.MaxBar
)  
SELECT  Data.foo
        , q.bar
        , CASE WHEN q.bar = Data.bar THEN Data.baz ELSE 0 END
FROM    q
        CROSS APPLY Data
ORDER BY
        Data.foo
        , q.bar
```

**Test script**

```
WITH Data AS (
  SELECT [foo] = 1, [bar] = 1, [baz] = 2
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, 3, 4
), q AS (
  SELECT  [bar] = MIN(bar)
          , [MaxBar] = MAX(bar)
  FROM    Data
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT  q.bar + 1
          , q.MaxBar
  FROM    q
  WHERE   q.bar + 1 <= q.MaxBar
)  
SELECT  Data.foo
        , q.bar
        , CASE WHEN q.bar = Data.bar THEN Data.baz ELSE 0 END
FROM    q
        CROSS APPLY Data
ORDER BY
        Data.foo
        , q.bar
```

Comment: @Alexey, I have slightly changed the statement to start from 1 io MIN(bar) just in case MIN(bar) would be different to 1.

Answer (score 2):

create following tables

table_foo

```
foo|
-----------
1  |
2  |
```

table_bar

```
bar|
-----------
1  |
2  |
3  |
```

After that, this query should do the trick:

```
select * from  table
UNION
(
    select 
        table_foo.foo,
        table_bar.bar,
        0 
    from
        table,
        table_foo, 
        table_bar
    where 
        table.foo != table_foo.foo and
        table.bar != table_bar.bar
)
```

Comment: @Curt, That should be expected since in the question Baz is Zero for all rows except the rows that were already present.

Comment: @Shamit In the initial question, when foo=1 & bar=1, baz=2. I don't think this is true with your example

Comment: This seems simplest and most portable. Would be nice to avoid temporary tables, but I can certainly live with them.

Comment: @Curt Oops, I see what you mean.

Comment: @Curt First part of query is:

select * from  table

This should produce "foo=1 & bar=1, baz=2" because this row is present in table.

And if both foo and bar are 1, that would be filtered out by second query that has (table.foo != table_foo.foo and table.bar != table_bar.bar)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your table is called MyTab, this sql will produce the second table of data (I'm assuming MSSQL):

```
select 
    f.foo,
    b.bar,
    baz = coalesce(m.baz,0)
from 
    (select foo = 1 union select foo = 2) f
    cross join (select bar = 1 union select bar = 2 union select bar = 3) b
    left join mytab m on f.foo = m.foo and b.bar = m.bar
```

Comment: I assume Alexey needs a solution that works with whatever rows are present in the table. This solution works but it would need adjusting every time rows are changed or added.

Comment: @Lieven - Just working to the spec! - "I am interested in values 1,2 for foo and 1,2,3 for bar". I like your solution as a generalized case, but if he's only ever going to have these possible values then a simpler solution is best.

Comment: following your logic, a `select 1, 1, 2 union all select 1, 2, 0 union all...` would even be simpler <g>.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @foovalues table (foo int) -- values 1,2 for foo
insert into @foovalues values (1) 
insert into @foovalues values (2)

declare @barvalues table (bar int) -- values 1,2,3 for bar
insert into @barvalues values (1) 
insert into @barvalues values (2)
insert into @barvalues values (3)

declare @table table (foo int, bar int, baz int) -- your data
insert into @table values (1,1,2)
insert into @table values (2,3,4)

select x.foo, x.bar, isnull(baz, 0) as baz
from (select f.foo, b.bar from @foovalues f, @barvalues b) as x
left outer join @table t on t.foo = x.foo and t.bar = x.bar
order by x.foo, x.bar
```